# How to automatically refresh Excel file with Microsoft Flow when source data is modified?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow, refresh

I have a master Excel file saved that consolidates financial data for different teams. The team data is updated in separate excels so that the teams can only see their specific excels, but it flows to an identical corresponding tab in the master Excel. (Team data cells in master Excel refer to corresponding cells in each team's Excel).

Ideally I would like to use Microsoft Flow to trigger a refresh of the master Excel whenever one of the source data Excels are updated. When I tried the update file command, it turns the master Excel into a copy of the updated source Excel (ie. removes all other information).

Can I use a different setting to make the flow work (currently using Update file content) or is there another work-around for this?